# What high school subjects build strategic thinking?

Tags: career-path, teaching

I am trying to provide some guidance and incentive for a senior high school student showing a particular interest/strength in strategic thinking. They have asked me which subjects I think they could learn more about this and use it, since their current subjects are lacking this.

They are an avid gamer and enjoy activities involving complicated strategizing and problem solving. Maths does this to some extent but the real world applications are not always there.

They haven't yet chosen a career path specifically but if I were to have a guess I would think areas such as Project Management, Leadership & Strategy and perhaps Marketing/Advertising. They also haven't ruled out trying to work in the military.

Any suggestions on which subjects I should point them towards?

Comment: I don't think any subject in high school really promotes strategic thinking. That's just not a goal of the curriculum. My strategic thinking at high school revolved around how I could optimize my grades while minimizing effort.

Comment: I suspect your question is off-topic. This site is for questions about academia starting from the graduate level.

Comment: @Roland some high school's offer electives in business education such as management, marketing which I believe do require strategic thinking?

Comment: student government, model UN, debate, leadership roles in other school groups...

Answer (score 1):

The actual branch of science that deals with strategic decision-making is game theory, but it is premature to try to learn this formally in high-school (the theory and maths would probably be too difficult at that level).  At a high school level, I'd say a reasonable proxy for learning strategic thinking is for the student to involve themselves in a range of competitive or cooperative games (e.g., board games, card games, team sports, etc.) that have a strategic component where optimal actions depend on the action of other players.  That could lead to a general interest and rough heuristic knowledge in strategic principles that are formalised in game theory.

(If it helps, here is an [academic paper on optimal strategy in the children's game *Guess Who*](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0247361).  The mathematical elements of the paper would certainly be too difficult for a high-schooler to understand, but they might be able to get a general heuristic understanding of some of the broad strategic ideas in the paper.  It would be a useful exercise for a high-schooler to try playing some games to test out different strategies and see if they are able to understand the heuristic ideas of the strategic optima.  They might also like to start thinking about optimal strategies in other simple children's games.)